# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray

Tags: java, android, exception, nosuchmethoderror, fileutils

Method `readFileToByteArray(File file)` is present in imported jar file in android project.

[image]

But still getting this error at runtime when try to test the project:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray
    at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.<init>(DexFileReader.java:240)
    at com.example.dex2jar.MainActivity.dextojar(MainActivity.java:67)
    at com.example.dex2jar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How are you testing the project? It is most likely Android Studio is resolving a different version of the library than whatever you are testing with.

Comment: I am running this project on emulator for testing.

Comment: I am using this to read/ write DEX file.

Comment: What does the dependency in your Gradle build file look like?

Comment: I can't say the reason exactly, but one is possible: Maybe you added right version of apache commons, but one of your dependencies uses other version of apache commons without this method. Check you dependency tree and ensure that only one version of apache commons is in the project.  (If you use idea, Ctrl+N and N and type FileUtils)

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to explictly declare the version of `commons-io` you want to use. Something like this: `compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'`.

Most likely, some other dependency is pulling in the wrong version of `commons-io` at runtime, which is why you are seeing that error only when you actually run your app.